# How to integrate waze data with my web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, integrate

Waze is an application, which offers an actual traffic information. There is also a livemap [Waze livemap](http://world.waze.com/livemap/) - where are marks as you can see.

So, I found some site: [Check this link - egaraz](http://www.egaraz.cz/traffic) and I'm really curious how did egaraz.cz fetch (parse) data (marks) from Waze, because there is no chance to do that. Or do they have some kind of deal? I don't know.

I tried to download all mentioned webpages to my computer, I read all javascript files and everything and found just nothing. Maybe I overlooked some...

Can you just help me and (try to) say me how do they did that? Or suggest some working solution/s..

Comment: site link is a google map... what does WAZE have to do with it?

Comment: what an answer... don't you see that markers on site (egaraz.cz) are from Waze?? even after click on the specific marker (usualy in Slovak rep. - it's country on the right), see, that there stays "zdroj: Waze" - it means "Source: Waze"...

Comment: Share your solution, please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some investigation on this and found some curious stuff...

It seems it's sort of hidden but there's a Waze Wiki, here's your answer:

> API - use waze maps on your website
>
> For further information please contact bizdev@waze.com

http://www.waze.com/wiki/index.php/API_-_use_waze_maps_on_your_website
(so maybe you gotta pay for it, anyhow, they're probably interested in knowing what you wanna do beforehand)

Now the interesting part is that Waze source **was** actually open ( seems it's not the last version tho )
https://github.com/mkoloberdin/waze
,
http://www.waze.com/wiki/index.php/Source_code **(edit: link is down)**

And a guy even did a Linux backport( didn't see if it works yet )

https://github.com/sashakh/waze

Edit: Theoretically it could be possible to hack an integration but this is old stuff, Waze stopped releasing the source since v3.0 and it's possible that they've probably added additional barriers to the data(I've actually ran the linux port after making this post and it seemed to work, that was the farthest I went tho)

Comment: It's very old topic, I found a way how to do that, so it's closed for me. Your effort is appreciated though :)

Comment: would you share what you found out?

Comment: just checked out the other answer below and it seems to be working good. when you enter the coordinates of a zone you want to get waze traffic notification you get a response with all the details, you can display them on a map

Answer (score 2):

open-source project that wrapper waze functionality

its written in java. can be used as a service or as a runnable server.

https://github.com/Nimrod007/waze-api

link to docs:

http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Nimrod007/waze-api/blob/master/docs.html

it has an endpoint for traffic information according to given coordinates.

Comment: updated answer with details about how to integrate the points to the map